# Why can't I update database using ef6 code first mysql migrations?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Having a problem implementing code first with ef6 connecting to a MySql db on godaddy. It's still trying to connect to a SQL instance

I get the following error when I run `update-database`

> Error Number:53,State:0,Class:20
>   A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

here's my app.config:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="LMScontext" connectionString="Server=servername;Database=dbname;Uid=user;Pwd=password;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>

    <providers>
      <!--<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />-->
      <!--<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />-->
    <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.10.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"/>
    </providers>

  </entityFramework>
 <system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
      <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.10.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>
</configuration>
```

Comment: This is database connection error stating, that your connection string is either incorrect or not specified. 

You will have to check if the server name, database name, username and password are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution that works in my case is,

Add below the line on just above `<providers>.....</providers>`

```
<defaultConnectionFactory type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data" />
<providers>
  ...
</providers>
```

Then remove `<DbProviderFactories>.....</DbProviderFactories>` part from `web.config` or `app.config`.

And then add below attribute to `DbContext` class implementation

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))]
```

So that it look like,

```
[DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration))] 
public class MySqlDbContext : DbContext 
{
    .....
}
```